# Determining if given matrices are dependent or independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad{} B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad{} C=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I need to determine if these matrices are linearly dependent or linearly independent.

Now, in order to do that I'll take three arbitrary real numbers $\alpha, \beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$

$$ \alpha\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \beta\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix} +\gamma\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So now I have to form a system of $4$ equations with three unknowns

$$ \alpha + \beta + 2\gamma = 0 \\\ 0\alpha + \beta - \gamma = 0 \\ \alpha + 3\beta + \gamma = 0 \\ \alpha + 2\beta + \gamma = 0$$

Now we know, from the second equation, that $\beta = \gamma$, so we have the following system of equations

$$ \alpha + 3\beta = 0 \\ \alpha + 4\beta = 0 \\ \alpha + 3\beta = 0$$

since first and third equations are the same, it means that we have two equations now

$$ \alpha + 3\beta = 0 \\ \alpha + 4\beta = 0 $$

Since this system has no solutions except when both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are zero, which means that then $\gamma$ is zero too. This would mean that these matrices are linearly independent. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Yes i am quite sure this is correct if you havenot done anything wrong with algebra

Comment: It's correct. The only point is you might have shortened,, considering the matrices as elements of $\mathbf R^4$ and proceeding to row reduction.

Answer (score 0):

just did this in matrix form (writing matrices as columns), got the same result, you should be good!